# "The few houses she owns": does it imply too small a number?

Tags: meaning, quantifiers

a. The few houses she owns are big.

b. Those few houses she has renovated are very expensive.

c. The small number of houses she owns are big.

Do these sentences imply that she has few houses? In other words, do they imply that their number is, for some reason, too small?

Comment: The number of houses is small, but not necessarily *too* small. It is probably a smaller number than the speaker would think of as normal.

Comment: @Peter - I wonder where that speaker might be located, given that in the UK (by no means a poor country) many people (36%) don't own any houses at all, and the overwhelming majority of those who do are the owners of one single house.

Comment: I wondered whether the speaker might be among a group of property owners. For the second sentence there are of course people who earn income from buying, renovating, and then selling houses at a profit.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - But the grammar is the same for any noun. _The few clothes she owns are shabby_.

Comment: @KateBunting - yes, or pairs of shoes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by saying that A & B make sense, but C does not.

(A) suggests she owns a few houses - perhaps not as many as other people with a portfolio of houses.

(B) suggests that she has *renovated* a few houses - it doesn't mention how many she owns. Perhaps she owns more but hasn't renovated the others yet? But again, by using 'few' the inference is that it is fewer in comparison to other people in the same business of renovating houses to sell them.

(C) is wrong because the subject is not the houses, it is "the small number". You wouldn't say "*the small number is big*" for a number of logical and grammatical reasons.

In answer to your question - A & B don't imply that the number of houses owned/renovated is *too* small. Actually, the opposite. As I mentioned, 'fewer' is a comparative term. It suggests she has fewer than other people. However, this is countered in both cases by the fact that the houses are *big* and *expensive*, so actually it seems to imply overall that she buys fewer houses but they are bigger and worth more, so perhaps that is better?

Answer (score 1):

**Not too small, but smaller than what might be expected (from the context).**

- > The few houses she owns are big.

  This implies that she owns fewer houses than, for example, people mentioned before (and that they are bigger than or all big in comparison to the houses of the others).
  This sentence could for example be encountered in an article about maintenance costs for home owners: where others might deal with a larger number of houses, the fewer houses she has are larger.
- > Those few houses she has renovated are very expensive.

  This implies she has renovated a small number of the houses she owns/she hasn't been able to renovate all of them/the renovated properties have increased in prize/she has renovated the more expensive houses.
- > The small number of houses she owns are big.

  This isn't necessarily about comparison, but just to say that she doesn't have a large number of houses (which is still more than most people, so still dependent on context). (Note that the grammar is [debatable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461492/the-number-of-x-societies-is-or-are) here.)